# Improve positioning of favorites in your search results

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, search

Questions that you have personally favorited should be more visible in search results. I would recommend an implementation like Google Starred Search where favorited results can appear in a single line format up at the top.

Answer (score 2):

How about we just have them first in sorting order, with some type of UI look to point them out (like coloring, or a star next to them, etc.)?

Comment: By making them smaller, may be just one line high they wouldn't push the rest of the results beyond "The Fold". Just one reasoning to present them the way the OP proposed.

Comment: The main advantage of showing favourites in single line format is that it matters less when the algorithms matching is completely off

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just me, but don't the Search function and the Favorites system kinda serve opposing goals? Search is used to obtain the location of information that you do not have. Favorites mark the location of information that you have already found so you can easily find it again. So, if your Searches prioritized your own Favorites to the top... your search would turn up information you already have!

Or maybe you're a person who favorited a question because you had the same question and you wanted to wait for an answer. Favoriting gives you a nice way to get back to the question when someone does decide to answer it. If you have already found the question in order to mark it a favorite, then why would you be trying to find it again through a search?

Comment: "favorited results can appear in a single line format up at the top" - this method shows you questions you found before, while also allowing you to easily find new questions.

Comment: @Casebash I like that your suggestion promotes a method which is not obstructive, and I understood that. My concern is not with new questions being pushed down. It's that I don't see why favorites should be highlighted, so to speak. By setting the favorites at the top, distinguished by stars or size or format, attention is being drawn to them, specifically attention which may not be necessary. If a favorite of mine is to show up in a search I do, I would much rather it showed up in the order of relevance determined by the search engine, than at the top as if it were more relevant.

Comment: The problem is that writing a search engine that weighs favourites correctly is hard. It is likely that it will either put too many favourites into the results, or not enough. By giving favourites only a single line, the cost of showing irrelevant results is reduced.

Comment: @Casebash I'm questioning why favourites should be given any weight at all. I personally think that with the scope of the Q&A site, designating favourites in a search is neither helpful nor harmful. With no net gain or loss, it seems impractical to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really like it if, when I search for something, any results that are in my favorites are marked with a star.

I suppose it would be good if my favorites in other contexts (main page question lists, tag question lists) would also be marked with a star.